# Perforce - How do I know whether a workspace has the latest revision file?

Tags: perforce

I did a `p4 have file.c` in my workspace and also in another colleague's workspace for the same branch. my revision is shown as #5 and colleague's is #4. His rivision remains #4 even after he doing `p4 sync -f file.c`. Still I dont get the reason for this mismatch- (`p4 sync -f` is supposed to bring to latest revision which is #5).

The question is, how somebody can confirm whether their file is the latest version available in the perforce server.

Comment: by the way, I got reason for this mismatch - it was some server side configuration issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for new changes with `p4 sync -n` or `p4 changes "...#>have"` in the workspaceroot.

A possible cause for not getting a new change when calling `p4 sync` or `p4 sync -f` is to have the file open (you'd have to resolve it then).